# MySQL - LEFT JOIN value of columnX where MAX(columnY)

Tags: mysql, max, left-join

So this is my query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wagons.id, 
                       wagons.mid, 
                       wagons.year, 
                       wagons.make, 
                       wagons.model, 
                       wagons.nickname, 
                       wagons.description, 
                       members.first, 
                       members.last, 
                       wagon_photos.filename, 
                       Count(DISTINCT( likes.id ))    AS likes, 
                       Count(DISTINCT( comments.id )) AS comments 
FROM   wagons 
   INNER JOIN members 
           ON members.mid = wagons.mid 
   LEFT JOIN wagon_photos 
          ON wagon_photos.wid = wagons.id 
   LEFT JOIN likes 
          ON likes.wid = wagons.id 
   LEFT JOIN comments 
          ON comments.wid = wagons.id 
GROUP  BY wagons.id 
ORDER  BY wagons.id DESC 
LIMIT  10
```

I am trying to fetch the `wagon_photos.filename` where `wagon_photos.default` is the maximum value. (It's a boolean, where only one row *(for each `wagon_photos.wid`)* will be 1.) On the off-chance the member does not have a default photo selected, I'd like it to return the lowest `wagon_photos.id` if possible.

I have tried numerous queries with ORDER BY and GROUP BY, but I think it may be a little more complicated than that. If I use a WHERE clause, it left out any wagons that did not have any photos linked to it, which I do not want to do.

---

```
CREATE TABLE `wagons` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mid` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `make` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext,
  `featured` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `visibility` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `commision` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `feat1title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feat2title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feat3title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `feat4title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=617 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `wagon_photos` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `wid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caption` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `default` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I'm re-reading this and now I'm not sure that I answered your question.  Can you post what your tables look like?  And I'm not sure what you're referring to by 'default set'.

Comment: Well, not a "set", but a boolean set as TRUE. If a member has 6 photos, one will be 1, 5 will be 0. I want to return the row with the "default" column set to 1. If there isn't one set for some reason, pick the row with the lowest id. I'll add the table structure above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel a little bit silly now.

I finally thought of adding  `AND wagon_photos.default = 1` after the LEFT JOIN for wagon_photos and it works. I just need to make sure they always have a default setup, so I ran a script that on every update to their photos, it checks for a default, and if one isn't set, set the newest upload as default.

```
... LEFT JOIN wagon_photos ON wagon_photos.wid = wagons.id AND wagon_photos.default = 1 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and understand what you're asking.  I think what you're asking is "how do I construct a query where I want to select all of the items that have the max value of a particular column".  If that's the case, you want to break this down into simpler units in order to solve it.  First, you'll need the max value itself:

```
select max(wp.default) as max_val from wagon_photos wp
```

This gets you the max value.

Next you can create a query to select rows where a condition is true, but leave the condition out for a moment:

```
select (your rows) from wagons w where (a condition will go here)
```

And your condition is that you want wagon_photos.default to equal the max value.  So you'll need to join in that table:

```
select (your rows) from wagons w join wagon_photos wp 
on wp.wid = w.id where wp.default = (something)
```

Your "something" happens to be that max_value that we created a query for in the beginning.  So putting this together, you'll use a subquery which will look like this:

```
select (your rows) from wagons w join wagon_photos wp
on wp.wid = w.id where wp.default = (
    select max(wpb.default) from wagon_photos wpb
)
```

I haven't set up the tables myself to run this, so I might have goofed on parentheses, and it doesn't include all your joins.  But I think this should point you in the right direction.